# Поиск по карте яндекс(api 2.1) с учетом местоположения

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как в яндекс карте делать поиск через `ymaps.suggest` с учетом местоположения пользователя. Суть такова, у человека есть поле, куда он начинает вводить город, к примеру Минск. под полем выводится подсказка через `ymaps.suggest` но по умолчанию выдается поиск по росиии. А как определять местоположение пользователя и передавая параметр в `ymaps.suggest` искать относительно его?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиск по карте осуществляется [методом `search`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/?from=SO#search), при этом `ymaps.suggest` служит только для отображения поисковых подсказок.

И поиск, и саджест позволяют задать границы области карты, где предположительно находится нужный объект, через опцию `boundedBy`. Если опция задана, то в первую очередь поиск будет происходить в указанной области, и только потом по остальной карте. Также эта область будет учитываться при ранжировании результатов поиска.

Для решения вашей задачи проще всего сначала [определять местоположение пользователя](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolocation?from=SO), а затем передавать границы видимой области карты в опцию `boundedBy` саджеста.

Comment: понял, придется определять местоположение пользователя самому. Спс